# Params[:id] returning ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I need help figuring out why I'm getting a ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound Error when I attempt to retrieve an object by it's ID. Below is my error and code. Please let me know if any other files need to be added to this post. Thank you in advance for the help!

**Error**

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in WikisController#show

Couldn't find Wiki with 'id'=edit

def show
    @wiki = Wiki.find(params[:id]) #Highlighted line within error
    authorize @wiki
end
```

**Controller**

```
class WikisController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]

  def index
    @wikis = Wiki.visible_to(current_user)
    authorize @wikis
  end

  def new
    @wiki = Wiki.new
    authorize @wiki
  end

  def create
    @wiki = current_user.wikis.create(wiki_params)
    authorize @wiki

    if @wiki.save
      flash[:notice] = "Wiki was saved."
      redirect_to @wiki
    else
      flash.now[:alert] = "Error saving Wiki. Try again."
      render :new
    end
  end

  def show
    @wiki = Wiki.find(params[:id])
    authorize @wiki

    unless @wiki.private == nil
      flash[:alert] = "You must be signed in to view private topics."
      redirect_to new_session_path
    end
  end

  def edit
    @wiki = Wiki.find(params[:id])
    authorize @wiki
  end

  def update
    @wiki = Wiki.find(params[:id])
    authorize @wiki

    if @wiki.update_attributes(wiki_params)
      flash[:notice] = "Wiki was updated."
      redirect_to @wiki
    else
      flash.now[:alert] = "Error saving the Wiki. Try again."
      render :edit
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @wiki = Wiki.find(params[:id])
    authorize @wiki

    if @wiki.destroy
      flash[:notice] = "\"#{@wiki.title}\" was deleted successfully."
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      flash.now[:alert] = "Error deleting Wiki. Try again."
      render :show
    end
  end

  private

  def wiki_params
    params.require(:wiki).permit(:title, :body, :role)
  end
end
```

**Routes**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :wikis
  resources :charges, only: [:new, :create]

  devise_for :users
  resources :users, only: [:update, :show] do
    post 'downgrade'
  end

  get 'welcome/index'
  get 'welcome/about'
  root 'welcome#index'
end
```

Comment: please add your routes. it seems edit route is wrong..

Comment: @Tucker I usually use `find_by(attrs_hash)` to preemp this error. It will return nil if no record is found, and allow you to handle that case.

Comment: @Shani - Just added the routes. It's definitely a route issue as my URL is generating `wikis/edit` rather than `wikis/id/edit`. What am I missing here?

Comment: can you paste your code for generating url please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you are accessing `wikis/edit` URL instead of `wikis/:id/edit`. Make sure your link is correctly generated in your view.

Comment: You're right, I just noticed that my URL is wikis/edit rather than the ID being in there. I just posted the routes.

Comment: What is missing from my routes that's causing the id portion of the URL to be missing? Bare with me please, I'm still fairly new to Rails.

Comment: Could you add your view where that link is being rendered here please? That would help us to pin point the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure in your view you have something like this (if using erb):

`<%= link_to edit_wiki_path(@wiki) %>`

Also you can definitely shorten up your controller using `before_action`

```
class WikisController < ApplicationController
  ...
  before action :set_wiki, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  ...

  private

  def set_wiki
    # Now this is being set in your show, edit, update, destroy method
    # Make sure to delete from the above mentioned methods
    @wiki = Wiki.find(params[:id])
  end
```

Comment: That is an awesome way to shorten/clean up the controller. I'm learning Rails so this is new to me. Thanks for that! As for my error, I just realized my URL isn't being generated right. I'm getting `wikis/edit` rather than `wikis/id/edit`.